# Locally installed TYPO3 doesn't load TypoScript record edit

Tags: typo3

I'm new to development and just started with a local TYPO3 installation on my Mac. I've installed PHP 8.2 with home-brew on this computer and after that installed TYPO3 for my localhost. Everything works fine except the part of 'edit the whole TypoScript record'.

When clicking on that the page is loading infinity, without endings, nothing happens here.
Any advice what I could do? Already asked google for that problem but have found nothing at least. Hopefully someone could help me out here.

[image]

Ive tried to google my problem - no results. Already edited the php.ini as TYPO3 installation was recommended.

Comment: Your browser console should give you an idea what's going wrong as it's certainly a JavaScript or CSP (content security policy) problem.

Comment: Btw. It's a TypoScript record, that's different than Typescript, they exist both and need to be distinguished. There aren't any Typescript records at all though, Typescript is used in files only.

Comment: As recommended by David please check the browser console. Further more, check the logs in the TYPO3 backend and in var/logs/ of your installation. For local development you should use something like [DDEV](https://ddev.com/). That's much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another browser! I had the exact same issue only on my server online. Did you use Safari by any chance? When i switched to Firefox everything was loading as it should!